conditional to determine if a value is within a range in another table and return true/false
Here's the data:
Refusals:



agent_name
refuse_time




John
1/10/2024 12:48:47 PM


Sally
1/26/2024 11:03:34 AM


John
1/18/2024 01:31:24 PM


John
2/2/2024 09:14:09 AM



Clicklog:



cdate
agent_name
action




2024-01-10 12:48:37 PM
John
User did something to window 2


2024-04-24 12:48:57 PM
Sally
User did something to window 1


1/26/2024 11:03:44 AM
Sally
User did something to window 2



I realize the dates are all messed up and in different formats. I already have it converted to timestamp. Assume for now that I have the date conversions figured out.
I want to be able to know if an agent clicked on "window 2" within -30 seconds of refusal_time and simply return a true/false. The return of the query should be all fields from Refusals and a new column that says TRUE/FALSE if the condition above is TRUE.
In the case of the data above, I would expect the following output:



agent_name
refuse_time
Agent_Clicked




John
1/10/2024 12:48:47 PM
TRUE


Sally
1/26/2024 11:03:34 AM
FALSE


John
1/18/2024 01:31:24 PM
FALSE


John
2/2/2024 09:14:09 AM
FALSE



Note that Sally returned FALSE because her click happened 10 seconds after the refusal_time (only care about within 30 seconds before).
Thanks!

Here is a working SQL query and test data that illustrates one solution:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.refusals` (
  agent_name STRING,
  refuse_time TIMESTAMP
) AS
SELECT "John", TIMESTAMP("2024-01-10T12:48:47") UNION ALL
SELECT "Sally", TIMESTAMP("2024-01-26T11:03:34") UNION ALL
SELECT "John", TIMESTAMP("2024-01-18T13:31:24") UNION ALL
SELECT "John", TIMESTAMP("2024-02-02T09:14:09");

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.clicklog` (
  cdate TIMESTAMP,
  agent_name STRING,
  action STRING
) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-01-10T12:48:37"), "John", "XXX" UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-04-24T12:48:57"), "Sally", "XXX" UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-01-26T11:03:44"), "Sally", "XXX";

SELECT *, EXISTS(
    SELECT agent_name FROM `test.clicklog` as C
    WHERE C.agent_name = R.agent_name AND C.cdate BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(R.refuse_time, INTERVAL 30 SECOND) AND R.refuse_time
  ) AS agent_clicked
  FROM `test.refusals` as R

